# Plotly scatter not drawing line of markers above certain number of data points

Tags: python, plotly

I am using [Plotly's scatter](https://plotly.com/python/line-and-scatter/). I want to have lines surrounding the markers, like in this plot (the black contour):

[image]

I want this to happen by default, so I am setting a template like in the below MWE:

```py
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.io as pio
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import numpy as np

MARKERS = ['circle', 'cross', 'x', 'triangle-up', 'star', 'hexagram', 'square', 'diamond', 'hourglass', 'bowtie', 'pentagon', 'triangle-down', 'triangle-left', 'triangle-right', 'star-triangle-up', 'star-triangle-down', 'star-square', 'star-diamond', 'diamond-tall', 'diamond-wide', 'triangle-ne', 'triangle-se', 'triangle-sw', 'triangle-nw',  'hexagon', 'hexagon2', 'octagon']
my_template = pio.templates['plotly']
my_template.data.scatter = [
    go.Scatter(
        marker = dict(
            symbol = s, 
            line = dict(
                    width = .5,
            ),
        ), 
        error_y = dict(
            width = 1, 
            thickness = .8
            )
        ) for s in MARKERS
]
pio.templates['my_template'] = my_template
pio.templates.default = 'my_template'

import numpy
import pandas

N_SAMPLES = 99 # Set to 9999 and it fails.

fig = px.scatter(
    pandas.DataFrame(
        {
            'x': numpy.random.randn(N_SAMPLES),
            'y': numpy.random.exponential(size=N_SAMPLES),
        }
    ),
    x = "x",  
    y = "y", 
)
fig.show()
```

This works perfectly but if the number of points goes beyond certain value, it stops drawing the lines, like this:

[image]

This is what happens to me when I change `N_SAMPLES` to e.g. `9999`. How can I get it to work independently of the number of points?

I have Python 3.8.10 and Plotly 5.11.0.

Comment: I tried your code in my environment and it displays fine with N=9999. If the data size is large, WebGL can be used, please refer [here](https://plotly.com/python/line-and-scatter/#large-data-sets).

Comment: I tried both WebGL and "normal", none of them is working here... I am with Python 3.8.10 and Plotly 5.3.1.

Comment: The latest version of plotly is 5.11.0, so if you don't mind, please try the latest version.

Comment: Upgraded already. Still the same...

Answer (score 0):

To cope with the large amount of data, WebGL is available, so I used it to draw a scatterplot with blue markers and a line width of 1. N number is 100,000.

**Update:**
To set the line width of a marker by default, create a dedicated template and set the line width as its content.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

my_template = go.layout.Template()
my_template.data.scattergl = [go.Scattergl(marker=dict(line_width=0.5))]

N = 100000
fig = go.Figure()
fig.update_layout(template=my_template)
fig.add_trace(go.Scattergl(
    x = np.random.randn(N),
    y = np.random.exponential(size=N),
    mode='markers',
    # marker=dict(
    #     color='blue',
    #     line_width=1
    # )
))
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: How can you make the `marker=dict(line_width=1)` a global setting that applies by default to all plots?

Comment: See [here](https://plotly.com/python/templates/#the-template-data-property) for template customization.